# How to use Mapbox Map in .NET MAUI Mobile App?

Tags: mapbox, maui, mapbox-gl, mobile-development, mapbox-android

How to use Mapbox Map service in .NET MAUI app? We need to use the route api services...Is there any service package available ?

I tried Mapbox.Maui(Version 10.11.1.1) NuGet package. But it not compatible with MAUI app.
Please let us know if any solution...

Comment: https://tuyen-vuduc.tech/how-to-use-mapbox-in-your-dotnet-maui-app

Comment: Hi @Jason,

As I mentioned in my question,  the package from your given link, its not compatible with MAUI project. When we Install the package- Mapbox.Maui(Version 10.11.1.1) , the project is not able to build.

Getting this error:   >

Gradlew build failed \\..MapBox.Maui.Map\obj\xgradle\gradlew.bat --> MapBox.Maui.Map \\.nuget\packages\dependencies.gradle\7.6.0.1\buildTransitive\Dependencies.Gradle.targets

Comment: just because you are getting an error does not mean that it is "not compatible".  Have you tried filed an issue with the library author?

Comment: @Jason, I was trying to fix the build error. I will report an issue with concerned team. Apart from this package, any open source library is available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jason suggested, you can use MAUI component for Mapbox: [Mapbox.Maui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mapbox.Maui#readme-body-tab).

> Gradlew build failed \..MapBox.Maui.Map\obj\xgradle\gradlew.bat -->
> MapBox.Maui.Map
> \.nuget\packages\dependencies.gradle\7.6.0.1\buildTransitive\Dependencies.Gradle.targets

For the above error, you can try to revert to the version `10.11.1`. And I also notice that someone else has encountered the same error as you met, see https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/578#discussioncomment-7300820, the author hasn't responded to it yet. You can follow up on that thread or open a new one via [this link](https://github.com/tuyen-vuduc/mapbox-maui/issues).

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, I logged one issue the said link. Will see.. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: @Abhi Thanks for the response, I'll provide any update and add to my post if the author responds to it. Have a good day!

Comment: Hi @AlexandarMay-MSFT, I didnt get any solution for this. Any other options for the same  ? Thanks

Comment: I see the author updated, see:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/578#discussioncomment-7527712

Comment: Hi Alexandar, I saw that comments.. But as he mentioned in his comments, in visual studio, he is also getting some errors. don't know what is the solution. I tried like that, but failed. I installed the latest version, but no use. 
Are you getting the same error in your side? using visual studio 2022